# Add overlay on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some trouble with overlays.
I want to create a page where on a button click, lets say "Login" button, a small popup window should appear to accept username and password etc. And the background should get applied with overlay.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Take a look at modals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap modal to do this and create a login form in it. Like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

For more details visit this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first you create a division that cover whole page using transparent background.After that create another new  division in that div .

```css
#model{
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:800px ; //Height of the screen 
 background:rgba(30,30,30,0.7);
}
```

```html
<div id="model">
 // your form here goes ...
</div>
```